# Interaction between rotated and externalfigure

Tags: metapost

In the following snippet, I'm rendering a rotated square and two images.  If *rotated 0* is used, then everything works, but if *rotated 1* is used, then the second image gets shifted to the left significantly.  This problem goes away if the *rotated 1* is put on the path rather than the picture, but for other reasons, I'd like to be able to rotate pictures. Is there some explanation for this behavior?

```
verbatimtex
%&latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
etex
beginfig(0);
% from https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/27/MPlogo.svg/220px-MPlogo.svg.png
draw image(draw ((0,0)--(0,-100)--(100,-100)--(100,0)--cycle)) rotated 1;
externalfigure "220px-MPlogo.svg.png" xyscaled (200, 50);
externalfigure "220px-MPlogo.svg.png" xyscaled (200, 50) xshifted 200;
endfig;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, the output is correct in ConTeXT (after changing `externalfigure` to `draw externalfigure`):

```
\starttext
\startMPcode
draw image(draw ((0,0)--(0,-100)--(100,-100)--(100,0)--cycle)) rotated 1;
draw externalfigure "220px-MPlogo.svg.png" xyscaled (200, 50);
draw externalfigure "220px-MPlogo.svg.png" xyscaled (200, 50) xshifted 200;
\stopMPcode
\stoptext
```

gives

[image]